# Why does clang_complete in VIM give incomplete completion?

Tags: vim, clang-complete

I am new to VIM and clang_complete. I managed to install clang_complete and it seems to work, but the completions are somehow not what I expect.
For example, I looked at a tutorial and expect a behaviour like in this animated gif:
https://blogueun.files.wordpress.com/2013/12/be5ee-using_clang.gif

This is what I do:

- `vim test.cpp`
- In VIM I hit `i` to get to insert mode
- I press `<C-x><C-u>` to open the autocomplete list
- I press `<C-n>` twice to select the second entry
- I hit enter to confirm the selection

Now I have the following line in VIM:

`using`

But I think it should be something like:

`using namespace $\'identifier'` (the ' has to be replaced by `, please edit the question)

How can I get the full completion and not only the first word?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out myself. From the FAQ of clang_complete in https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Rip-Rip/clang_complete/master/doc/clang_complete.txt:

> *) Only function names get completed but not the parentheses/parameters.
>
> Enable the snippets-support by adding the following lines to your
> .vimrc, for example:
>
> `let g:clang_snippets = 1`
>
> `let g:clang_snippets_engine = 'clang_complete'`

This worked for me.